# Does the Hungary embassy in India keep my passport during residence permit application processing?

Tags: hungary

I am from Bangladesh and going to apply for residence permit in Hungary embassy in India because I am going to study there. Now the website shows the residence permit application processing takes 15 days. But I have to come back to Bangladesh after submitting the application and I want to go back to collect the visa when ready.

Comment: Why don't you just apply from Bangladesh, then?

Comment: @SJuan76 There is no Hungarian embassy in Bangladesh.

Comment: @jpatokal I see; I had some idea that in case of an EU country not having an embassy you could use the consular services of some other EU country embassy, but now that I am reading about it I only find references to consular protection, which obviously is not what the OP needs.

Comment: @SJuan76 also that rule only applies for a Schengen visa C, not a resident visa D.